# Precision difference in VB6 and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I got two different result in VB 6 and VB.NET for a same code, which handles division operation.

```
ABC = 9.999728
result = IIf(ABC <> 0, 1 / ABC, 10 ^ 10)
```

In VB6, I got result = 0.1000027

In VB.NET, the result is 0.100002721

However, when I use `CSng(Val(CStr(result)))` in VB.NET, I get 0.1000027.

1) Why VB.NET produces different precision compared to VB6?

2) Why `CSng(Val(CStr(result)))` produces same precision as VB6?

3) This may look trivial and simple, but this problem is repeated and propagates to my final result, which is different from the equivalent result in VB6. Can I safely assume that VB.NET result is more precise than VB6 and discard the VB6 result completely?

Comment: try `CDbl(Val(CStr(result)))`

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are getting a default double precision in .NET vs. the default single precision in VB6.

Comment: If `result` is Single or Double, then `result = IIf(ABC <> 0, 1 / ABC, 10 ^ 10)` wont compile under `Option Strict`.

Comment: Both results are correct, a variable of type Single can only store 7 accurate digits.  The rest are just random noise.   An obvious way to get ahead is to simply declare ABC as Double instead, that gets you an extra 8 accurate digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB6:

```
Dim ABC, result

ABC = 9.999728
result = IIf(ABC <> 0, 1 / ABC, 10 ^ 10)
MsgBox result
```

Displays:

```
0.100002720073986
```

Randomly using `CSng()` will of course truncate precision, and the obsolete `Val()` function should be avoided like the plague.  If you want a Double then use `CDbl()` instead.